# How can I post a photo and caption in the same publish on a facebook group api using FormData and axios?

Tags: javascript, typescript, facebook-graph-api

Someone could help me, I'm trying to send a photo and caption into a group, but isn't working!
I'd like send the photo that I recieve as base64 and send to a facebook group api.

What I'm doing?  I got the base64 then convert into buffer and write it on a local disk, then I read it into a formdata.
I load the data into a form this way =>

```
const form = new FormData();
    const fileContent = Buffer.from(url as any, 'base64');

    fs.writeFile('../tmp', fileContent, (err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
    })


form.append('groupId', groupId)
 form.append('caption', caption) 
form.append('image ', fs.createReadStream('../tmp'))
```

In below is the axios configurations and request

```
 await client.post(`${config.facebook.BASE_URL}/${groupId}/photos`, form, {
  headers: {
    ...form.getHeaders(),
    Authorization: `OAuth ${config.facebook.token}`,
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    file_type: "image/jpeg",
  }

})
```

Note: This way I got the Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: What, if anything, did the response body contain?

Comment: Try not to set the Content-Type header yourself. multipart/form-data needs a boundary specified, but by giving the header yourself, you might be overwriting that.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for you anwser, but I already resolve this although I change de way that the file came to me. instead of receiving the image in base64 I'm receiving a signed url from google storage, and on the form. append, it's necessary to pass the name and the extension of the file, like this =>      form.append('source', image, 'file.jpg');
of course together with the other params and axios' configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved this although I changed de way that the file came to me, instead of receiving the image in base64 I'm receiving a signed url from google storage, and on the form.append, it's necessary to pass the name and the extension of the file, like this =>      form.append('source', image, 'file.jpg');
of course together with the other params and axios' configurations